# Teams: App policy adding app to every team

Tags: microsoft-teams

is there an option to make a policy or running an powershell command to add a specific app to ever Team.

My problem:

In my School ther are a lot of Teams (100 or so). Now we want to add an App (Sharepoint Document Libary)
to every to a specific channel whithin an team, so the students can use it. Is there an easy or do i have to add it manually to every Team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Graph APIs to automate this. Use [Add a tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-beta)  Graph APIs to configure new tab to your channel. Please take a look at example on how to [Configure Document library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#document-library-tabs) tab.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/tabs
{
    "displayName": "Document%20Library1",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.files.sharepoint",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "",
        "contentUrl": "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/WWWtest/Shared%20Documents",
        "removeUrl": null,
        "websiteUrl": null
    }
}
```